# I have a problem with .each() function that gives me an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using JS code to have a gdpr compliance pop up that is showing a user that the website is using cookies. I added the JS function, call it on website footer, but I am getting the console error, and pop up is appearing, but I can not close it on click on the accept button.

I tried debugging, changing the order of scripts that I included on the website. I even turned off all other scripts and still, nothing happened.

```
var n = "local" === o.storage ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("cookiesConsentDate")) : "session" === o.storage ? parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("cookiesConsentDate")) : parseInt(a.cookie("cookiesConsentDate")),
            t = this.length ? this : a('<div>', {
                html: '<p id="demo" class="cookie-text col-md-10">' + o.message + '<a style="' + o.learnMoreStyle + '" href="'+ o.learnMoreLink +'"> '+ o.learnMoreText + '</a></p>',
                class: o.possition + ' ' + 'row' + ' ' + 'ccwrap',
                style: "z-index:9999;background:white;font-size:14px;position:fixed;width:100%;padding:1rem 1rem;background-color:white;color:#333;text-align:center;display:none;" + o.style
            }).append(accept).append(decline).prependTo(a("body"));
        return o.onInit.call(t), o.testing || !n || n + 864e5 * o.consentTime < (new Date).getTime() ? a(t).show() : a(t).hide(), t.each(function() {
            var e = a(this);
            a(this).prependTo(a("body")), a(this).find("." + o.acceptClass).click(function() {
                "local" === o.storage ? localStorage.setItem("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime()) : "session" === o.storage ? sessionStorage.setItem("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime()) : a.cookie("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime(), {
                    expires: new Date((new Date).getTime() + 864e5 * o.consentTime),
                    path: "/"
                }), e.slideUp(), o.onConsent.call(e)
            }),
            a(this).prependTo(a("body")), a(this).find("." + o.declineClass).click(function() {
                "local" === o.storage ? localStorage.setItem("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime()) : "session" === o.storage ? sessionStorage.setItem("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime()) : a.cookie("cookiesConsentDate", (new Date).getTime(), {
                    expires: new Date((new Date).getTime() + 1),
                    path: "/"
                }), e.slideUp(), o.onDecline.call(e)
            })
        }
```

The error is

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
    at Function.ea.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at ea.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ea (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (cookieconsent.min.js?ver=1.0:58)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.cookieConsent (cookieconsent.min.js?ver=1.0:56)
```

on line 56 on t.each function.

Comment: Please check [CookieYes GDPR](https://www.cookieyes.com) free solution if it satisfies your needs.